# Function to return a day n days ahead of given day

Tags: function, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

So I'm looking to build a function that takes an int and a day (of my day type below) and returns the day n days ahead of the given day.

I have type day defined as

```
type day = Sun | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thurs | Fri | Sat;;
```

and a function that returns the next day:

```
let next (d:day) : day =
    match d with
  Mon -> Tues;
 | Tues -> Wed;
 | Wed -> Thurs;
 | Thurs -> Fri;
 | Fri -> Sat;
 | Sat -> Sun;
 | Sun -> Mon;
;;
```

I'm looking to build a function as stated above, I'm thinking it needs to make recursive calls to next to keep incrementing the day until it is n days ahead but I am totally stumped on how to define this in OCaml. I've tried to define a few things but have so far only created a function that does the same thing as next such as:

```
let rec ndays (n:int) (d:day) : day =
  if n=0 then next d else ndays (pred n) d;;
```

I feel like this is close but as we all know, close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades. Does anyone have any tips on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, what is f7 in your code. In fact, what is the fn notation supposed to mean?

If I understand you correctly you're looking for a function like so:

```
let rec next_n d = function
  | 0 -> d
  | n -> next_n (next d) (pred n)
# next_n : day -> int -> day
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, i changed the name for one copy but not the other, let me edit!

Comment: The bar just denotes that d could be different things right? Could we modify this so the initial function takes in an int and a day? such as let next_n (n:int) (d:day) : day = .....

Comment: yes you could. `function` is just a short hand syntax for a taking an argument `n : int` in our example and immediately patter matching on it. You could rewrite my example to read: `let rec next_n d n = match n with ... ` and it would be equivalent. Also note that the type annotations are not necessary. OCaml will infer them.

Comment: Ahh ok, that is the style I am more familiar with. Thank you!

Comment: You will see both styles out there a lot so it's still good to familiarize yourself with both.